# Using String.Format() Method in .NET 5.0 in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am a new user to C# and I am having difficulty with one last thing to finish this script I am working on.  I am in .NET 5.0. I am working on writing some results out to a csv file but when I use the string.Format() method, I am only getting the first value returned to the console, or the csv for that matter.

```
string newLine = string.Format("Value1", "Value2");
Console.WriteLine(newLine);
```

I am inside of a loop, and all lines are being returned, buy only Value1 is being returned on each line, not Value2.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation and examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format)?  What result are you expecting here and, more importantly, *specifically why* do you expect that result?

Comment: you do not include formatting placeholders.

Comment: What do you expect the result of `string.Format("Value1", "Value2")` to be, and how is that expectation justified by the documentation?

Comment: Please **do not** write CSV by hand if string.Format is a problem for you, use a library that does that correctly (ok, don't write CSV by hand even after you learn string.Format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand how `string.Format()` works at all. The first argument is a base string, which should include **placeholders** (ie: `{0}`, `{1}`, etc). Additional arguments then fill in the placeholders in order.

So if you want CSV data, it sounds like you want something more like this:

```
string newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", "Value1", "Value2");
Console.WriteLine(newLine);
```

Or from an array like this:

```
string[] row = {"Value1", "Value2"};
string newLine = string.Format("{0},{1}", row);
Console.WriteLine(newLine);
```

Or maybe you'd prefer `string.Join()`, which can handle an arbitrary number of values without needing placeholders:

```
string[] row = {"Value1", "Value2"};
string newLine = string.Join(",", row);
Console.WriteLine(newLine);
```

But really, even simple CSV files have a surprising number of edge cases and gotchas, and you'll likely be MUCH better off to get a CSV library from NuGet.